# fixed widths with css and percentages

Tags: css

Currently I'm trying to fix a div class to always be 80% of the screen size if that's possible? I don't want the div to resize when I change the size of my browser, would I be better using media queries?

```
.main{
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: *to always be 80% of the screen size* != *I don't want the div to resize when I change the size of my browser* ... you need to know what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write

> I don't want the div to resize when I change the size of my browser

Well, then use a fixed width in pixels:

```
.main{
    width: 600px; /* or whatever value you wish */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: So I will need media queries for different sized screens? 
I was hoping to do a one size fits but keep it static, media queries it is I guess

Comment: yes, if you always want fixed sizes (and not percentages). But an often used method is to use a percentage value for `width` and pixel value/s for `min-width` and/or `max-width`. That way the width will change up to / down to a certain screens size (percentage) and above/ below that remain a fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want your div to be `80%` of screen size. use `viewport` units. `vw` in your case which means viewport width.

This way your div will always be 80vw out of 100vw which is the full viewport size.

See below

```css
.main {
height:100px;
width:80vw;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"> </div>
```